# How to avoid empty elsif?

Tags: perl

The below code does exactly what I want, but something tells me, that the empty `elsif` is not good practice. The purpose is make sure `$type` is either `snap` or `fs`, but only change `$t` if `snap`.

```
my $t = "";
if ($type eq "snap") {
    $t = "-t snapshot";
} elsif ($type eq "fs") {
} else {
    fatalError("must either be snap or fs")
}
```

**Question**

How do I do the same, but without the empty `elsif`?

Comment: Use a colon (`:`) as a pointless/null statement.

Comment: Honestly, I like the flow of that. It clearly lists the valid options, with the error handling in the `else`. I'd *add* a comment saying "Nothing to do", but that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
my $t = "";
if ($type eq "snap") {
    $t = "-t snapshot";
} elsif ($type ne "fs") {
    fatalError("must either be snap or fs")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would just:

```
my $t;
if ($type eq 'snap') {
    $t = '-t snapshot';
}
elsif ($type eq 'fs') {
    $t = '';
}
else {
    fatalError("must either be snap or fs");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're actually combining two separate checks into one:

1. Is `$type` valid?
2. What should `$t` be set to?

I think the following makes that clearer, at the expense of checking the same value twice:

```
fatalError('must be either snap or fs') unless $type eq 'snap' or $type eq 'fs';

my $t;
$t = '-t snapshot' if $type eq 'snap';
```

(This of course assumes that your function `fatalError` actually causes the program to die.)

You could generalize the first part to work for more than two valid options like this:

```
my %valid = map { $_ => 1 } qw(snap fs foo bar);
fatalError('must be one of: ' . join(', ', keys %valid)) unless exists $valid{$type};
```

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your condition and get rid of the else.

```
} elsif ($type ne "fs") {
    fatalError("must either be snap or fs")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $t =
  ($type eq "snap") ? "-t snapshot"
: ($type eq "fs")   ? ""
: fatalError("must either be snap or fs");
```

Comment: Yuck, nested conditionals. Code as if the next person to get your job will know your home address ;)

Comment: Technically nested, yes, but laid out the same as if/elsif/else and practically no different. And not nearly as ugly as the if/elsifs above. It's an idiom, get used to it...let the ternary operator be your friend.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - If the next person to work on this can't handle simple crap like this, they shouldn't be programming. Next you'll be telling me you shouldn't use pre or post increment because it's too confusing...